# Joining Dataset Fields with missing values in multiple fields

Tags: sql, join

I have two datasets let's call them dataset A and dataset B

Dataset A is as follows:

| Business Name | Business Code | Business Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Example A | 123 |  |
| Example B | 456 | Some Description |
| Example C |  | Another Description |
| Example D |  |  |

Dataset B is as follows:

| Business Code | Business Description |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | A Description |
| 456 | Some Description |
| 789 | Another Description |

My question is how do I join the tables so that Dataset A will have all of the null values filled in? Would this just be a simple Inner Join such as:

```
Select *
From Dataset A
JOIN Dataset B
ON Dataset A.Business Code = Dataset B.Business Code
```

Would this fill in the null values in Dataset A's Business Code and Business Description? Or wowuld I also have to perform another join such as:

```
Select *
From Dataset A
JOIN Dataset B
ON Dataset A.Business Description = Dataset B.Business Description
```

in order to fill out Dataset A? I'm fairly new to SQL and I haven't come across something like this before and was wondering if someone could help me out with understanding how this would be done.

Comment: Are there any cases where both `Business Code` and `Business Description` are both `NULL`, or is it always 1 of them filled at least?

Comment: Oh, Good catch! Yes, there are a few cases where both are NULL. Sorry about that I will add that in the table!

Comment: share your output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query treats the cases when only 1 of the columns (`Business Code` and `Business Description`) is NULL, and supposes `Business Name` is UNIQUE.

```
UPDATE DatasetA A
JOIN (SELECT
    A.BusinessName,
    B.BusinessCode,
    B.BusinessDescription
FROM DatasetA A
JOIN Dataset B ON B.BusinessCode = A.BusinessCode
WHERE A.BusinessDescription IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    A.BusinessName,
    B.BusinessCode,
    B.BusinessDescription
FROM DatasetA A
JOIN Dataset B ON B.BusinessDescription = A.BusinessDescription
WHERE A.BusinessCode IS NULL) t ON A.BusinessName = t.BusinessName
SET 
    A.BusinessCode = t.BusinessCode,
    A.BusinessDescription = t.BusinessDescription
```

Comment: This is awesome, Thank you! It does exactly what I was looking for!